# Android several Asynctask running same time

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

i woking json.

I successfully created Tabhost(viewpager), I have 3 fragments in viewpager and each fragment i parsed json and show it to listview(images and text).

I wrote code witch can parse json each fragment (different is only URL). It is working but I have one problem: each fragment i used Asynctask to parse json from server. My problem is all three asynctask class running same time.

When program is starting this three Asynctask running same time this is a my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, MainActivity.TabInfo>();
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }

    this.intialiseViewPager();
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void intialiseViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, SendItemsFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, RecivedItemsFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FavoriteItemsFragment.class.getName()));



    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
            super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) super
            .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void centerTabItem(int position) {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    final TabWidget tabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    final int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getWidth();
    final int leftX = tabWidget.getChildAt(position).getLeft();
    int newX = 0;

    newX = leftX + (tabWidget.getChildAt(position).getWidth() / 2)
            - (screenWidth / 2);
    if (newX < 0) {
        newX = 0;
    }
    horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(newX, 0);
}

private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Send").setIndicator(
                    "Send"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Send",
                    SendItemsFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Recived").setIndicator(
                    "Recived"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Recived",
                    RecivedItemsFragment.class, args)));

    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Favourite").setIndicator("Favourite"),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Favourite", FavoriteItemsFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);



    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {

    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        //tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sa_green));
    }
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    centerTabItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

private class TabInfo {
    private String tag;
    private Class<?> clss;
    private Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }

}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
```

}
and this is a one of fragment code(first)

```
public class SendItemsFragment extends Fragment {
public ListView list;
private String URL = "**************";

public static String KEY_name = "name";
public static String KEY_id = "id";
public static String KEY_uid = "uid";
public static String KEY_type = "type";
public static String KEY_title = "title";
public static String KEY_lat = "lat";
public static String KEY_long = "long";
public static String KEY_image = "image";
public static String KEY_time = "time";
public TextView name, id1, type, title, lat, longitute, time, image;
private int screenSize;
private Adapter adapter;
public JSONParser jsonparser;
public JSONArray jsonarray;

public LoadDataAllChanelsToServer loader;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public EditText search;
public TransparentProgressDialog pd;
public TextView Txtlongitude, Txtlatitude, Txtname, Txtid, Txttype,
        Txtimage, Txttime;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_items, container, false);

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sendlistView1);
    pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.drawable.loader);
    screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    loader = new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer();
    loader.execute();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Txtlongitude = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.viewpager_long);
            Txtlatitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_lat);
            String Stringlongitude = Txtlongitude.getText().toString();
            String Stringlatitude = Txtlatitude.getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), HistoryResult.class);
            in.putExtra("longitude", Stringlongitude);
            in.putExtra("latitude", Stringlatitude);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private class LoadDataAllChanelsToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        Log.e("Facebook URl", URL);

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("name", jsonobject.getString(KEY_name));
                map.put("id", jsonobject.getString(KEY_id));
                map.put("uid", jsonobject.getString(KEY_uid));

                map.put("type", jsonobject.getString(KEY_type));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));

                map.put("lat", jsonobject.getString(KEY_lat));
                map.put("time", jsonobject.getString(KEY_time));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));

                map.put("long", jsonobject.getString(KEY_long));

                itemList.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemList.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), itemList, screenSize);
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (loader != null) {
            loader.cancel(true);
            loader = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

}

another fragment's code is a same different is only URL
if anyone knows solution please help me thanks

Comment: what is the question ma'am ?

Comment: i do not need to run this theee AsyncTask same time.when i moving between fragmens this AsyncTask running everytime and for example if my URl contains(json URL) 4 items  then i have 8 items

Comment: So hold objects of AsynkTasks & cancel them when you don't need them anymore

Comment: i wrote onDestroy method and not working .please look my code

Comment: Ok... ! so you start your app > load the first fragment and swipe to next fragment > then again swap to third fragment... and all `Asynctasks` are running... ! and you want that a `Asynctask` should only run when a fragment is visible ??

Comment: Actually in a `ViewPager` fragments are not destroyed as soon you move to next fragment so try cancelling the Asynctask prior to onDestroy like in onPause

Answer (score 0):

Use [executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) mothod with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) as first argument. For API below 11 use `execute()`